# React Native CLI Setup for both IOS and android

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I am trying to start a react native project using the React Native CLI method (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).  My first question is, if I have a mac and my friend has a windows computer can we both work on the same app?  Also, how do I configure one single code base for both ios and android?  Do I just follow the installation instructions for both in a single project?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can work separately on windows and mac for the same app and you don't have to configure any kind of codebase as react native is hybrid app development technology, you just have to write a single code for both the android and ios platforms.
To install react native CLI just follow the official document on your specific platforms because both of them have a slight difference in the installation process, after successful installation, I would suggest you to use some kind of VCS(Version controlling system) like git or svn.

I am also working in the same process as you have described I am developing in windows and my friend is working on the mac.

feel free to contact me I will help you if you have any kind of queries

Comment: When using the cli through the docs it makes you choose a target os between andriod and ios. So it does not matter what I choose? I mean as you mention it works for both ios and andriod. So what does that choice mean?

Comment: It is for setting up the development environment for ios and android if you are having windows then just select android and follow the document for setup, if having mac then select ios, and if you want to work on android and ios both then complete your setup one by one in your mac os.